# vba format columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'trying to format columns on a newly created worksheet. I couldn't get selection and with statements to work, so I tried direct assignment and got the same problem (generic error 1004).  Last code I tried was:

```
    Sheets("Survey Data").columns("A").NumberFormat = "0"
    Sheets("Survey Data").columns("A").VerticalAlignment = x1Bottom
    Sheets("Survey Data").columns("A").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Sheets("Survey Data").columns("A").ColumnWidth = 5
```

When checking output, the `NumberFormat` seems to have worked, but not the three following statements.

Comment: Are you running this under an option explicit script, or no?

Comment: Can you post a sample workbook. I just ran this as is and in a `With` statement, and it worked like a charm!

Comment: I'm not sure about the option explicit script, so I'm posting the entire code below.  I've successfully created two extra sheets and populated the column headers, but hitting problems from then on.

Comment: Scott - How do I post a sample workbook?  It's too big to paste in the comment area.  Can I attach it or email you directly?

Comment: @IainMackintosh You upload it to a website, or share server such as dropbox, and then you post the link here for people to d/l

Comment: Thanks Matt - will use this for future reference.  Problem now fixed (see below), so Konstant has saved some bandwidth for the community at large!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
Sheets("Survey Data").columns("A").VerticalAlignment = x1Bottom
```

to

```
Sheets("Survey Data").columns("A").VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
```

I see a "1" (One) instead of a "l" (L). It should be **xlBottom** and not **x1Bottom**

Comment: It is lower-case "L" - same as in VerticalAlignment!

Comment: @IainMackintosh then can you please provide the excel version you are working on. There doesn't seem to be any problem with the code as such.

Comment: MS Office 2010 Excel 14.0.6123.5001 (64-bit), Win 7 Ultimate.  I suspect there must be an error somewhere else in my macro as I can't see any syntax errors either.

Comment: Aaargh!  I checked again and found it was '1' rather than 'l' - now working fine!  Thanks for the eagle eyes Konstant!